# Порядок добавления строчек в QListWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt5

Как перевернуть QListWidget. Чтоб он добавлял элементы в первую строку, а не в конец

Comment: я ответил на ваш вопрос ?

Answer (score 0):

> void QListWidget::insertItem(int row, QListWidgetItem *item)
>
> Вставляет элемент в позицию в списке, заданном строкой.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#insertItem

Comment: @Дмитрий-Лорез я ответил на ваш вопрос ?